# Check If User Input Is Valid

Tags: python, input, user-input

Current Code:

```
def character_a():

    character_a = input('Enter First Dot or Dash (. / -): ')

character_a()

if not character_a == "." or "-":
    print('Invalid Character.. Try Again')
    character_a()

else:
    print('Valid Character')
```

Hello Im trying to write a python script where it asks you for a input of either a "." or "-" only problem is that you can in theory do any other letter or number. And I got it to check if its a character like a,b,c,etc But not Numbers How Can i make sure they only do "-", ".". And for my future code how can I also check to make sure they either do "-", ".", or "0" And not some other random character/digit like ; or ] etc etc.

Comment: `if not character_a in ['.', '-', '0']:`

Comment: Note that your `character_a` variable only exists within your function, which returns nothing; so it won't exist after the function call. Or rather it will exist (it's the name of your function), but will never be equal to '.', '-' or any character.

Comment: You need to `return` your variable from the function, and then you need to assign it to something, e.g. `first_char=character_a(); if not first_char in ['.', '-', '0']:...`

Comment: Also see [How to ask a user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)